# priority of contents in a web page and putting one element in front of another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem on priority of contents in a web page. I mean I want one component to be in front of another component. here I want my drop down menu in front of other components when I hover the horizontal menu

[image: this is the problem]

and I want it to be in front of other components like this:

[image: this is how it should be]

here is the code that I have used to write this drop down menu:

```
<div id="horizontalmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">اخبار</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://es.sums.ac.ir/newsGilrsElementary">ابتدایی دخترانه</a></li>
<li><a href="http://es.sums.ac.ir/newsGilrsGuidance">راهنمایی دخترانه</a></li>
<li><a href="http://es.sums.ac.ir/newsGilrsHigh">دبیرستان دخترانه</a></li>
<li><a href="http://es.sums.ac.ir/newsBoysElementary">ابتدایی پسرانه</a></li>
<li><a href="http://es.sums.ac.ir/newsBoysGuidance">راهنمایی پسرانه</a></li>
<li><a href="http://es.sums.ac.ir/newsBoysHigh">دبیرستان پسرانه</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<style type="text/css" media="screen"><!--
#horizontalmenu ul { padding:1; margin:1; list-style:none; }    
#horizontalmenu ul a{ padding:1; margin:1; list-style:none; color:white;}   
        #horizontalmenu li { float:left; position:relative; padding-right:200; display:block;} 
        #horizontalmenu li ul { display:none; position:absolute; width:200px; background:#9a2d91;} 
        #horizontalmenu li:hover ul{ display:block; height:auto; width:200px;background:#9a2d91; } 
        #horizontalmenu li ul li{ clear:both; border-style:none; width:200px;background:#9a2d91;}
--></style>
```

can any one help me with this please?

Comment: you can use z-index property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was from z-index and the answer was to add z index in li tag like

```
<li style="z-index: 98;">
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
#horizontalmenu { z-index: 10; }
```

`z-index` represents the "altitude", the bigger the number the higher it is. The default being 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="div1">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dakirby309/windows-8-metro/128/Apps-HTML-5-Metro-icon.png"/>
      <div id="div2">
           <img src="http://penta2.ufrgs.br/edutools/composer/tutcomposer3.gif"/>
      </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {
    position:relative; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px;
}
#div2 {
    position:absolute; 
    top:60px; 
    left:6px;
}
```